# Can not get responsive menu to close

Tags: javascript

```js
//toggle image
var plus = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149187.svg';
var minus = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/128/128397.svg';

$('#resNavToggle').click(function() {
  if ($('.resNavIcon').attr('src') === plus) {
    $('.resNavIcon').attr('src', minus);
  } else {
    $('.resNavIcon').attr('src', plus)
  }
})


//open and close sub menu
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.resNavIcon").click(function(){
        $("ul.resNav").toggle();
   
    });


    $("li.serviceLink").click(function(){
        $("ul.serviceNav").show();
          $("ul.resNav").hide();
    });


    $("li.serviceNavClose").click(function(){
        $("ul.serviceNav").hide();
           $("ul.resNav").show();
    });
});
```

```css
.resNav       { display:none}
.serviceNav      { display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149187.svg" width="40" height="25"   class="resNavIcon"  id="resNavToggle">



<!-- Res Nav -->
<ul class="resNav">
<li><a href="">Main-menu</a></li>
<li class="serviceLink">Sub-menu ></li>
<li><a href="">Main-menu</a></li>
<li><a href="">Main-menu</a></li>
<li><a href="">Main-menu</a></li>
</ul>


<ul class="serviceNav">
<li class="serviceNavClose">< Main-menu</li>
<li><a href="">Sub-menu</a></li>
<li><a href="">Sub-menu</a></li>
<li><a href="">Sub-menu</a></li>

</ul>
```

I have created a very simple 2 tier responsive menu, please see:
https://jsfiddle.net/wmxujcy4/2/

Its taken a few tutorials to get the image toggle working to show the relevant 'open' and 'close' menu icon.

And I was able to get the sub menus working as required. As per the fiddle it all works OK until you are actually on the 'sub-menu' then pressing the main 'close' icon top left - should collapse both menus.

```
//toggle image
var plus = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149187.svg';
var minus = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/128/128397.svg';

$('#resNavToggle').click(function() {
  if ($('.resNavIcon').attr('src') === plus) {
    $('.resNavIcon').attr('src', minus);
  } else {
    $('.resNavIcon').attr('src', plus)
  }
})


//open and close sub menu
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.resNavIcon").click(function(){
        $("ul.resNav").toggle();

    });


    $("li.serviceLink").click(function(){
        $("ul.serviceNav").show();
                $("ul.resNav").hide();
    });


    $("li.serviceNavClose").click(function(){
        $("ul.serviceNav").hide();
                    $("ul.resNav").show();
    });
});
```

But both menus jam and the wrong icon shows instead of collapsing both menus. Please can some one help.

Comment: i think it might be nice to see some of your HTML.

Comment: There is a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/wmxujcy4/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wmxujcy4/20/

Comment: @uom-pgregorio comments are not meant for answers ;)

Comment: Yes that is the sort of thing - perfect! I will have to go through your code and check the tweaks. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertSheppard I only changed the `click` event handler for `.resNavIcon`. It's a simple `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the sub-menu is visible. If it is, just hide both `ul`.

```js
//toggle image
var plus = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149187.svg';
var minus = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/128/128397.svg';

$('#resNavToggle').click(function() {
  if ($('.resNavIcon').attr('src') === plus) {
    $('.resNavIcon').attr('src', minus);
  } else {
    $('.resNavIcon').attr('src', plus)
  }
});


//open and close sub menu
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img.resNavIcon").click(function() {
    if ($("ul.serviceNav").is(":visible")) {
      $("ul.resNav").hide();
      $("ul.serviceNav").hide();
    } else {
      $("ul.resNav").toggle();
    }
  });

  $("li.serviceLink").click(function() {
    $("ul.serviceNav").show();
    $("ul.resNav").hide();
  });

  $("li.serviceNavClose").click(function() {
    $("ul.serviceNav").hide();
    $("ul.resNav").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.resNav {
  display: none
}

.serviceNav {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149187.svg" width="40" height="25" class="resNavIcon" id="resNavToggle">



<!-- Res Nav -->
<ul class="resNav">
  <li><a href="">Main-menu</a></li>
  <li class="serviceLink">Sub-menu &gt;</li>
  <li><a href="">Main-menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Main-menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Main-menu</a></li>
</ul>


<ul class="serviceNav">
  <li class="serviceNavClose">&lt; Main-menu</li>
  <li><a href="">Sub-menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Sub-menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Sub-menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if sub menu is visible hide else toggle

```
$("img.resNavIcon").click(function(){
        if($("ul.serviceNav").is(":visible")){
            $("ul.serviceNav").hide();
      }else{
        $("ul.resNav").toggle();
      }

    });
```